# Android: sms PERSON attribute different than _ID of contact

Tags: android, database, attributes, contacts

I've some problems with android database.

I've to fill a contactObject class from the default android database with the following code :

```
/**
 * this function fill a contact with a given phoneNumber
 * @param phoneNumber the phone number to fill the contact
 * @return the recently created contact
 */
public Contact fillContact(String phoneNumber) {
    Contact contact = new Contact(phoneNumber);
    contact.setName(phoneNumber);
    ContentResolver cr = getCurrentContex().getContentResolver();
    Uri uri = Uri.withAppendedPath(ContactsContract.PhoneLookup.CONTENT_FILTER_URI, Uri.encode(phoneNumber));
    Cursor cur = cr.query(uri, null, null, null, null);
    if (cur.getCount() > 0) {
        while (cur.moveToNext()) {
            String id = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
            String name = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));
            contact.setId(Integer.valueOf(id));
            contact.setName(name);
        }
    }
    cur.close();
    return contact;
}
```

However, when I want to recover SMS from `Telephony.Sms` table, `PERSON` attribute is different than `contact.getId()`.

How can I get the equivalent of PERSON attribute in a Contact ?

Thanks a lot.